# Addthis linked is pop up window not working

Tags: linkedin-api, popupwindow, addthis

I am trying to implement add this code to a site , I would like to open facebook,twitter,linkedin and email windows as pop up when any one click on the buttons . I am also using cutomized buttons here . All other except linked in works perfect , but linked is not opening in a pop up window instead it opens a seperate tab window. How can I solve this ? Please see the code here

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>


 <!-- AddThis Smart Layers BEGIN -->
 <!-- Go to http://www.addthis.com/get/smart-layers to customize -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/30 /addthis_widget.js#pubid=sunilkumarpkerala"></script>

 <!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
 <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
 <a class="addthis_button_facebook"><img src="http://mysite.com/workshop/shareimages/facebook.png"
     width="32" height="32" border="0" alt="Facebook" /></a>
 <a class="addthis_button_twitter"><img src="http://mysite.com/workshop/shareimages/twitter.png"
     width="32" height="32" border="0" alt="Facebook" /></a>
 <a class="addthis_button_linkedin"><img src="http://mysite.com/workshop/shareimages/linkedin.png"
     width="32" height="32" border="0" alt="Linkedin" /></a>
 <a class="addthis_button_email"><img src="http://mysite.com/workshop/shareimages/email.png"
     width="32" height="32" border="0" alt="Email" /></a>

 </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

You can see the live example [here](http://www.proudeon.com/workshop/test.html)

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Addthis Sharing Endpoints](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381265-addthis-sharing-endpoints) that doesn't uses their script and make it work how you want.